# Is the voice command "transfer" to transfer text from the dictation box to the application supposed to work?

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

Once I'm done dictating in the dictation box, I can transfer the text with the voice command "transfer text" or "click transfer".

The [official Dragon NaturallySpeaking manual](http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/customer-portal/documentation/userguide/chapter3/ug_chapter3_punctuation_dictation.asp) says that one can use the voice command "Transfer":

[image]

It doesn't seem to work for me:

[image]

Is the voice command supposed to work or is it a typo in the official Dragon NaturallySpeaking manual? (yes I tried to contact Nuance's customer support and I know I can create my own "transfer" voice command.)

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Have you tried saying "Transfer to (application)"? Or saying it in a more command-like tone, rather than just like the rest of your sentence?

Comment: Is it possible that you have to pre-cede the transfer command with some word or phrase that defines or seperates commands from the normal TTS operation?

Comment: In Dragon NaturallySpeaking the user indicates he is using a voice command by slightly pausing before saying the command. The voice command "Transfer text" works fine but not "Transfer" :/

Comment: well then you solved it :-) just take out the first sentance out of the question and put it as the answer.

Comment: @Psycogeek done!

Answer (score 0):

It is a typo.

To create a "transfer" voice command:

```
Sub Main
    HeardWord "transfer", "text"
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a "typo". You need to use the correct command, which is "click transfer" since this is a mouse action.

Alternately, if you don't want to say "click" before mouse actions you can go to Tools>Options>Commands and uncheck the various Require "Click" to... options to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Dragon Dictate 13 with Word Perfect.  In spite of downloading the fix for Word Perfect, I kept getting shuttled over to the Dictation Box.  After dictating and clicking on "Transfer" I lost what I had done.  Not being stupid I only tried it six more times.

To fix it, I went to Dictation Box Settings. Manually using Ctrl-C to copy the Dictation Box contents and Ctrl-V to paste it solved the problem.  PC 101.  Hard to believe. A major booby trap by Nuance.